# Docusign Connect Post content type

Tags: docusignapi

We are getting a 415 HttpStatus code after configuring our DocuSign Connect Webhook. What content-type should we be expecting? Right now, we are only looking for a Content-Type of application/xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text/xml` is sent in the Content-Type